# error while updating property of 'selection' of a view managed by: androidTextInput

Tags: react-native

Getting following error on android, IOS work fine,

Using **React Native Version 0.43.4**

> error while updating property of 'selection' of a view managed by:
>   androidTextInput

[image]

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/22723
Please upgrade to the latest react native version as it has recently been updated with this pull request

Here's a work around if you cannot update RN:
https://github.com/akalin-keybase/rn-text-input-bugs/blob/master/App.js.

Basically this enforces the selection change before text change (whenever rerendering is called) see _onButtonPress() in the github page above.