# Error while updating property transform of a view managed by RCTView

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I found this error in my android studio. after intall React-nativ-router-flux latest version for naviation, it works fine in ios environment
[image]

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385641/error-while-updating-property-of-selection-of-a-view-managed-by-androidtextin